# Powershell - check service state, coputer name & service name get from txt files

Tags: powershell

I try to get services status, here is my script:

```
$ServName = (Get-Content c:\servname.txt)
$ServiceName = (Get-Content c:\service.txt)

foreach ($serv in $ServName)
    {
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -ComputerName $Serv `
        | ? {$_.name -eq $ServiceName}
    }
```

When my service.txt file contains only one service name it work great, but if i add more than one service name it return nothing, no error just nothing.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps because you are comparing the names of individual services with an array of services ( $_.name -eq $ServiceName ). This will always fail hence no output.

Comment: You could try using the '-contains' operator e.g. ( $ServiceName -contains $_.Name ) which should work where $ServiceName is an array. You may need to force it to be an array though by using '$ServiceName = @(Get-Content c:\service.txt)'

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the -like operator in the form ($array -like $item) which will return $item if it is found in the array e.g. ? { $ServiceName -like $_.Name }

Comment: Hello anyb, thanks for your help, ? { $ServiceName -like $_.Name } work great :)